# Reading a file with unknown encoding

Tags: java, libgdx, file-format

I use libGDX for developing a game for Android platform. In my game, I'll have to parse some file that contain some settings (skin customisation, user map reader).

My current code works for, at least, two encodings : utf-8 and iso-8859-1 but when I parse an utf-16LE encoded file, there is an additional space between each character (seen that when I used System.out.println())

As I use libGDX, I'm using FileHandle class ([> FileHandle doc](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html)). I take a BufferedReader with the .reader(int buffersize) method and I use its .readLine() method.

Here is my test code :

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;


public class TestFileReader {

    private FileHandle skinFile;    // libgdx File like object
    private BufferedReader bR;      // read character-typed files
    private String line;            // for printing each line
    private Boolean loop;

    public TestFileReader() {
        System.out.println("=== Test started ===");
        skinFile = Gdx.files.internal("skin_UTF-8.ini");
        readFile(skinFile);
        skinFile = Gdx.files.internal("skin_UTF-16LE.ini");
        readFile(skinFile);
        System.out.println("=== Test finished ===");
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }

    private void readFile(FileHandle skinFile) {
        try {
            bR = skinFile.reader(1024);     // 1024 is arbitrary
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            showError("Error (" + e + ")");
        }

        loop = true;
        System.out.println("--- read started ---");
        while(loop) {
            try {
                line = bR.readLine();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                showError("Unable to read the next line (" + e + ")");
            }

            if(line == null) {
                // read finished
                loop = false;
            }
            else {
                // parsing
                line.trim();
                System.out.println("[" + line + "]");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("--- read finished ---");
    }

    private void showError(String error) {
        System.out.println("[Parser] " + error);
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
}
```

My two files contains this:

```
This
is
a
test
H3ll0
WORLD
&é"'(§è!çà)-
àà`zè`r´róíú
```

And the execution will print this (and can't copy/paste, there is a null byte somewhere I think):

[image: execution result]

**I would like to be able to read all files with an unknown encoding (at least, the major ones)**. What did I do wrong? (I'm a beginner with both libGDX and Java)

Comment: You should have a way to know what is the encoding store it somewhere, or let the user pass it etc.. as far as I know there is no universal way of determining any encoding. Why would sth that complex be available if the solution is only to store the info of that type of encoding ...

Comment: And btw your implementation works for  UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 because they are compatible by design.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll look forward to learning how to detect the encoding so. Maybe it's the proper way to handle the given files.

@concept3d In fact, the file can be in various encodings, it's determined by the end-user, not me. I'll just force the end-user to give me an utf-8 file.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You could be using the [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) api provided by Libgdx to handle your app's configuration settings instead of dealing with low level file formatting problems. (If you have nothing more advanced than string values to store)

Answer (score 0):

Those first 2 characters printed in the utf16 file is the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Using that you can decide which encoding is used (the lack of which will probably indicate a UTF8-compatible encoding)

Comment: That's correct, but the problem is that the BOM is optional.